# How to create a scope to get the last ten transactions with rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

Trying to add a scope to my transactions model to return the last 10 transactions by created_at

Answer (score 16):

```
scope :most_recent, order(created_at: :desc).limit(10)
```

Comment: Scopes are ugly?  Haha.  Not as ugly as class methods

Comment: How is this getting upvoted? Are scopes really on their way out?

Answer (score 14):

Use scopes

```
# Ruby 1.8 style
scope :recent, lambda { |num| order('created_at DESC').limit(num) }

# Ruby 1.9/2.0 style
scope :recent, ->(num) { order('created_at DESC').limit(num) }
```

Example Usage:

```
<% Organization.recent(10).each do |organization| %>
  <li><% link_to organization.name, organization %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Using the 1.9/2.0 is the correct stye of using Scopes even according to the Rails Best Practices Guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this operation on association you can directly limit the number of records getting retrieved from the association

```
class School
 has_many :students -> order(created_at: :desc).limit(10)
end
```