# Showing 'most recent' list of two model's objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, Guides and Listings. I want to show a feed of the most recent 10 Guides and Listings.

What's the best way to go about doing this in Rails?

I tried doing it through an instance variable in the controller, but this seems wrong. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: should it be 5 from each model, or 10 from each model?

Comment: Either way. I just picked the number arbitrarily. Let's say 10 from each.

Comment: @Taylor, hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be: **scopes**. You are basically asking this question: [How to create a scope to get the last ten transactions with rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744037/how-to-create-a-scope-to-get-the-last-ten-transactions-with-rails3), but as you are using Rails 4 I suggest learning more about Scopes in Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes.

Comment: Thanks. This gets the most recent bit, but my real challenge is how to show a list of both Guides and Listings combined. This is the only way I have stumbled upon... https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-polymorphism-to-make-a-better-activity-feed-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to scopes. There are always multiple ways to reach a destination. For this type of quick stabs at a subset of latest posts it is also possible to use a helper method which can be called from a view. It will return a collection of records which can be passed to a partial for render. You can combine and sort the results whichever way you need. The ((nbr_to_show) is my implementation, you can use a value directly.)

In your guides_helper.rb

```
   # Display the latest nbr_to_show guides
  def the_latest_guides(nbr_to_show)
    Guide.order("created_at DESC").limit(nbr_to_show)
  end
```

Might be helpful to see the view code as well

```
<%= render partial: 'guides/guide_partial', collection: the_latest_guides(10)} %>
```

Comment: P.S. Your sort definition may be different.

Comment: helper code should be at least moved to controller, but better to model as a scope

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to go about doing this in Rails?

In such scenarios, the convention is defining scopes instead of helper methods.

In your `Guide` and `Listing` model define two scopes:

*guide.rb*, *listing.rb*

```
scope :latest_feed, ->(n) { order(created_at: :desc).limit(n) }
```

*your_controller.rb*

```
@latest_guides = Guide.latest_feed(5)
@latest_listings = Listing.latest_feed(5)
```

Comment: I haven't used a lot of scopes in this manner. I'm trying to learn as well, new ideas, etc. What are the advantages of using scopes over a helper?

Comment: Scopes are to specify frequently used queries which can be referenced as method calls on the models. This return ActiveRecord::Relation object and therefore you will be able to chain scopes. Like `Model.latest_feed.about_food`

Comment: I have a main app page where I display different views on various tables--"Top 10 Restaurants" sorted by rating -- "Latest review posted" by date, that sort of thing, from a variety of tables. That's why I went with the helper, because my view is outside any controller, looking into tables. I don't know if model scoping would be helpful. Do you think it would? I'm always looking for better ways.

Comment: @Valerie, scopes are like helper-methods for models. Usually helpers used for display methods, but not for work with model collections, while scopes gives you flexibility while working with model collections

Comment: Very good to know this. Thank you for your explanation, @Avdept.

Comment: Worked yesterday implementing scopes for such purposes; Very good! Thank you @Avdept and Sharvy Ahmed